# Laravel 5.2 - phpunit - Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, homestead

Can you please help me solve this issue on my local homestead/vagrant machine?

When I run the command: PHPUnit

I getting this result

> PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> E
>                                                                                                                      Time: 1.97 seconds, Memory: 6.00MB
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                There was 1 error:                                                    
>
>                                                                                                                1) ExampleTest::testBasicExample
> ```
>
> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at /home/vagrant/Code/Project/vendor/php
>   unit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:134)
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                /home/vagrant/Code/Project/bootstrap/app.php:4
> ```
>
> /home/vagrant/Code/Poptin/tests/TestCase.php:20
>   /home/vagrant/Code/Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:85
>   /home/vagrant/Code/Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:64

Please help! I've tried everything!!!

TestCase File

```
<?php

class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    /**
     * The base URL to use while testing the application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://192.168.10.10';

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

ExampleTest File:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {

        $this->visit('/login')
            ->see('password');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste code from /home/vagrant/Code/Poptin/tests/TestCase.php

Comment: paste code snippet from your test

Comment: @SomeDev Added!

Comment: have you checked  the following out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Is there a reason you're changing `$baseUrl`? Remove this and run your tests in homestead.

Answer (score 5):

I've also had this issue.

I have solved this by just using preventive **headers_sent** function, so there was no need to delete the header() functions from my code:

```
if(!headers_sent()) {

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, GoogleDataStudio');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
}
```

For a small bulk of tests you can also use this:[alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44508219/5331196)

[In this answer there is a full explanation about this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/5331196)

Answer (score 5):

```
add stderr=true for phpunit.
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     stderr="true"
     ...
 </phpunit>
```

or use annotations

```
/**
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 */
```

resolved for me. i hope will help you.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved the issue for my case.

Comment: `stderr="true"` solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer. 
In one of my file, I added Header functions. So when I removed them. everything worked fine :)

Comment: That's not a solution :)