# Zend_Controller_Response_Exception: Cannot send headers;

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

when runing all test for zend application, this line:

```
protected function _getResp()
{
    if (is_null($this->_response))
        $this->_response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http();
    return $this->_response;
}
.......
$this->_getResp()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8', true);
```

generates following error:

> Zend_Controller_Response_Exception: Cannot send headers; headers
>   already sent in /usr/share/php5/PEAR/PHPUnit/Util/Printer.php, line
>   173

and as a result - test fails

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190292/phpunit-unit-testing-with-items-that-need-to-send-headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused because PHPUnit generates output before your test even runs. You need to inject a `Zend_Controller_Response_HttpTestCase` in your test case. This subclass of `Zend_Controller_Response_Http` doesn't actually send headers or output anything, and it won't throw an exception because it doesn't care that output has already been sent.

Simply add the following method to the above class.

```
public function setResp(Zend_Controller_Response_Http $resp) {
    $this->_response = $resp;
}
```

Create a new `Zend_Controller_Response_HttpTestCase` and pass it to `setResp()` on the object you're testing. This will also allow you to validate that the correct headers were "sent" along with the output.

Comment: I know this is kind of old, but where do you need to write this? I have the same exact problem, but I don't understand from your answer where should I write these lines, I tried in the main bootstrap also in the ControllerTestCase but with no luck

Comment: Are you using `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase`? It injects the `Zend_Controller_Response_HttpTestCase` response into the front controller in `bootstrap()`.

Comment: I still don't see an answer to Uffo's question (which I have as well). Which file does the setResp function go into? I tried adding the code to Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase, but it didn't work.

Comment: @blainarmstrong - Looking at the ZF source (1.12.1, 1.11.10, and 1.11.0) I cannot find `_getResp()`. In our testing framework I do the above in our PHPUnit bootstrap. However, you should be able to inject your own `Zend_Controller_Front` subclass that overrides `getResponse()` to return a new `Zend_Controller_Response_HttpTestCase`.

Comment: It worked for me! Thank you, but anyone can explain why PHPUnit will generate the output before the test runs?

Comment: @Truman'sworld PHPUnit outputs the version, author, and configuration file location before running any tests along with the individual test status and percentage complete while it runs them. It does this so you can see results immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have custom request and response objects: `My_Controller_Request_Rest` and `My_Controller_Response_Rest`.

What I did to solve this, I created a new `My_Controller_Request_RestTestCase` and `My_Controller_Response_RestTestCase`, which extend `Zend_Controller_Request_HttpTestCase` and `Zend_Controller_Response_HttpTestCase` respectively.

What [David Harkness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285873/david-harkness) suggested actually solves the problem. The only thing is that your objects must extend the HttpTestCase class corresponding to each class.

You need to create the setters for each object as you are not allowed to set them directly.

I have the following `ControllerTestCase` code:

`tests/application/controllers/ControllerTestCase.php`

```
abstract class ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    /**
     * Application instance.
     * @var Zend_Application
     */
    protected $application;

    /**
     * Setup test suite.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->_setupInitializers();
        $this->bootstrap = array(
            $this,
            'applicationBootstrap',
        );
        parent::setUp();

        $this->setRequest(new My_Controller_Request_RestTestCase());
        $this->setResponse(new My_Controller_Response_RestTestCase());
    }
}
```

My custom request and response objects have the following signature:

`library/My/Controller/Request/Rest.php`

```
class My_Controller_Request_Rest extends Zend_Controller_Request_Http
{
    // Nothing fancy.
}
```

`library/My/Controller/Response/Rest.php`

```
class Bonzai_Controller_Response_Rest extends Zend_Controller_Response_Http
{
    // Nothing fancy either
}
```

Now, this is what I couldn't figure out, how to avoid repeating the same code in `library/My/Controller/Request/Rest.php` and `library/My/Controller/Controller/Request/RestTestCase.php`. The code is the same in my case in Request/Rest.php and Request/RestTestCase.php as well as in Response/Rest.php and Response/RestTestCase.php, but they extend `Zend_Controller_(Request|Response)_HttpTestCase`.

I hope I made myself clear. I know the post is old, but I think it's worth to extend this a little bit more.