# How to capture output from Zend Controller Test dispatch method?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

While doing a controller test method, and running dispatch method I find it echos the output,

How can I capture that output instead of printing it to the commandline?

Answer (score 2):

You can use built-in support in PHPUnit: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.output

---

Edited from the old answer mentioning output buffering.

Comment: I was looking for something to do with the zend view renderer not to output the rendered output instead capture it

Comment: PHPUnit now supports testing output too: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.output

Comment: @Thibault PHPUnit itself captures content with ob_start so this should still work:

 public function testFail()
 {
  ob_start();
  echo 'foo';
  $renderedContent = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  $renderedContentAfterClean = ob_get_contents();

  $this->assertSame($renderedContent, 'foo');
  $this->assertSame($renderedContentAfterClean, 'bar');
 }

Comment: @Josef Thank you for the link. Although apparently, PHPUnit already does a `ob_start` in the `setUp`, so you can't capture output. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127252/phpunit-test-for-expected-headers

Comment: @Thibault It can be nested - so it implies you have to catch exceptions and call ob_end_clean if you do not want some debugging nightmares. :) (Of course - just using built-in solution would be much better.) header() function ignores ob_* functions so you cannot catch headers even outside PHPUnit.

Comment: @Thibault You're welcome. .) I've edited the old answer.